# How to bind fields dynamically to the Angular Controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My form has dropdown lists in the below fashion.
Main category : `|Dropdown A|` 
First sun-category : `|Dropdown B|` 
Second sub-category : `|Dropdown C|` 
Based on `|Dropdown C|`futher I will populate dropdowns 
**dropdowns**=`|Dropdown e|` `|Dropdown f|` `|Dropdown g|` and so on.. 
So, based on `Dropdown C` **dropdowns** will change.
I can bind `Dropdown A| |Dropdown B| |Dropdown C|` like this 
`ng-model="main-category",ng-model="sub-category", & ng-model="sub-sub-category" respectively`.
But how can I bind `|Dropdown e|` `|Dropdown f|` `|Dropdown g|` , because they keeps on changing whenever there `Dropdown C` changes?

**Sample  Code :**
Main category:

```
<select>
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>

</select>
```

Sub-category

```
<select>
  <option value="d">d</option>
  <option value="e">e</option>
  <option value="f">f</option>
  <option value="g">g</option>
</select>
```

Sub-sub category

```
<select>
  <option value="h">h</option>
  <option value="i">i</option>
  <option value="j">j</option>
  <option value="k">k</option>
</select>
```

Based on `sub-sub category` selection I want to show/hide dropdowns.

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

So, out of above mentioned, few dropdowns will be hidden/shown.
I am saying hidden/shown, because I don't know another way to manage this scenario.

Please help.

Comment: @RameshRajendran : My question is different, I am able to bind dropdown box  using `ng-model`, but there are many dropdown boxes that will appear for few selections, and will not appear for others. So my question is to how to manage this situation? For example if `Dropdown C` value is apple, then `dropdown r`,`dropdown s` will be visible, remaining will remain hidden.

Comment: Sorry, I have wrongly posted here. :(

Comment: okay, you can remove your `duplicate ` flag.

Comment: Please clarify by posting your actual HTML.

Comment: Please clarify do you need to show/hide dropdowns e, d and f based on selection of dropdown C

Comment: Updated question with sample code.

Comment: @shbht_twr: Like I said, I don't know whether to use ng-show/hide, or to populate dropdown from database.That's why I am asking this question.

Comment: <select ng-if="sub-sub-category ===..."> ?

Comment: Even if you populate from the database, you still need to have a backing model, and the element has to know whether or not it should be used.

Comment: @Brain: okay , but then there will be many conditions, beacause I will have many options in `sub-sub-category`.

Comment: You could try a tree pattern where each select posts the selection, and the return is a nested element of the next set of options. The view could recursively display a select as long as the next set of options exists. Reviewing this code might get you started: https://github.com/a5hik/angular-multi-select-tree

Comment: okay, I will give it a try.Suppose I want to do this with `ng-if` directive, then how can I achieve this?